# Error while creating Solr's collection

Tags: solr

I have downloaded solr 5.2.1 & also followed the instructions to run the solr instance at port 8983. While creating collections i have received below error:

[image]

Comment: Seems like it [might be living in org.apache.lucene.analysis.stempel.StempelPolishStemFilterFactory now](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/53981795fd73e85aae1892c3c72344af7c57083a/lucene/analysis/stempel/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/stempel/StempelPolishStemFilterFactory.java) - try that (or remove the field and the definition from the Schema). Any reason why you're doing 5.2.1 and not the most recent version?

Comment: thanks, I will try that. reason for having 5.2.1 is production env solr version is of same version 5.2.1 & need to replicate an issue in sandox :(